WordPress custom plugin's script isn't executing, why?
I'm trying to execute a JS code in my dashboard.js file but it just doesn't work.
wp-content/
└── plugins/
    └── desha-moulin/
        ├── desha-moulin.php
        ├── dashboard/
        │   ├── dashboard.php
        │   ├── functions.php
        │   └── dashboard.js
        ├── eleve/
        │   ├── eleve-details.php
        │   ├── eleve-list.php
        │   ├── functions.php
        │   └── eleve.js
        ├── cours/
        │   ├── cours.php
        │   ├── functions.php
        │   └── cours.js
        ├── assets/
        │   ├── css/
        │   │   ├── desha-moulin-styles.css
        │   ├── js/
        │   │   ├── admin-script.js
        │   │   ├── desha-moulin-ajax.js
        │   └── images/
        │       └── ...
        ├── includes/
        │   ├── admin-menu.php
        │   ├── ajax-functions.php
        │   ├── functions.php
        │   └── roles.php
        |   │   ├── js/
        │   |   │   ├── admin-script.js
        │   |   │   ├── desha-moulin-ajax.js
        └── languages/
            ├── desha-moulin-en_US.po
            └── desha-moulin-fr_FR.po

If I put the code in another file it's executed as expected but I want it to be in dashboard.js file.
I even added a simply console.log() call at the beginning of my JS file but it just doesn't work. I also added some error_log() calls to verify that my PHP code is working and it is:

Current hook: toplevel_page_desha-moulin-dashboard


dashboard.js is enqueued: http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/desha-moulin/dashboard/dashboard.js

This is my main file :
include_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'includes/functions.php';
include_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'includes/admin-menu.php';
include_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'cours/cours.php';
include_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'includes/roles.php';
include_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'eleve/eleve-details.php';
include_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'eleve/eleve-list.php';
include_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'eleve/functions.php';
include_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'includes/ajax-functions.php';
include_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'dashboard/dashboard.php';

// Enqueue scripts and styles
function desha_moulin_enqueue_scripts($hook)
{
    wp_enqueue_style('desha-moulin-styles', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'assets/css/desha-moulin-styles.css');

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('desha-moulin-ajax', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'includes/js/desha-moulin-ajax.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('desha-moulin-status-toggle', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'eleve/eleve.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('desha-search-eleve', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'eleve/eleve.js', array('jquery'), null, true);

    error_log('Current hook: ' . $hook); // Log the current hook

    if ($hook === 'toplevel_page_desha-moulin-dashboard') {
        $script_path = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'dashboard/dashboard.js';
        if (file_exists($script_path)) {
            wp_enqueue_script('dashboard', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'dashboard/dashboard.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
            error_log('dashboard.js is enqueued: ' . plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'dashboard/dashboard.js');
}
    wp_localize_script('desha-moulin-ajax', 'deshaMoulinAjax', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('desha_moulin_nonce')
    ));
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'desha_moulin_enqueue_scripts');

If someone has any idea what I'm doing wrong please let me know. Thanks!

Maybe the 'dashboard' handle is already registered by something else? Try using 'desha-dashboard' instead and see if that does anything.

Can you see the file being enqueued in the HTML source of the page? If so, have you tried viewing that file directly in your browser to see what's in there? And then, if it isn't what you expect, but not a 404, try adjusting the query string to see if you can cache bust.

As @cabrerahector says I just rename my file in desha-dashboard and not just "dashboard", and it works, thanks !
